# Access to model attributes and methods in Django 4.2 after async call for model object

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await, aiohttp

How to access to model attributes and methods in Django 4.2 after async call for model object?
Here is my model:

```
class ProjectModule(models.Model):
     ...
     url = models.URLField(verbose_name="URL")
     ...
```

I'm getting a coroutine with this func:

```
async def get_module_object(module_id: int):
    """Get module object."""
    try:
        return await ProjectModule.objects.aget(pk=module_id)
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponseServerError(f"Error: {e}")
```

After that I query a url with next async function:

```
async def call_url(url: str):
    """Make a request to an external url."""
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url=url) as response:
                return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return web.Response(status=500)
```

Finally in my next function I call for model and url and trying to get `model` object from coroutine

```
async def htmx_test_run_module(request, module_id: int):
    """Test run module with HTMX request."""
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            module_coroutine = await get_module_object(module_id=module_id)
            module = await module_coroutine  # first error is here

            response = await call_url(url=module.url)  
            response = await response_coroutine  # second error is here

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text(), "lxml")    
            tag = soup.find(
                module.container_html_tag, class_=module.container_html_tag_class
            )

            return HttpResponse(tag)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError(f"Error: {e}")
```

The first error is `Error: object ProjectModule can't be used in 'await' expression` and the second one is `Cannot find reference 'await' in 'ClientResponse | Response'`.

Finally pyCharm PRO can't provide me with autocomplete for `module` object after `module = await module_coroutine`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing double await ?
Try following.

```py
async def htmx_test_run_module(request, module_id: int):
    """Test run module with HTMX request."""
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            module = await get_module_object(module_id=module_id)
            response = await call_url(url=module.url)  
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text(), "lxml")    
            tag = soup.find(
                module.container_html_tag, class_=module.container_html_tag_class
            )
            return HttpResponse(tag)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError(f"Error: {e}")
```